# How to solve this seemingly difficult problem: $e^{iz}=\sec(z)+i\csc(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

So I was bored, and decided to do some complex analysis for fun. After a while, I came up with this:$$e^{iz}=\sec(z)+i\csc(z)$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at doing so:

So we have$$e^{iz}=\sec(z)+i\csc(z)\implies\cos(z)+i\sin(z)=\sec(z)+i\csc(z)\\\implies1=\dfrac{(\sec(z)+i\csc(z))(\cos(z)-i\sin(z))}{\cos^2(z)+\sin^2(z)}\\\implies1=1-i(\tan(z)+\cot(z))+1\\\implies i\tan(z)+i\cot(z)=1\\\implies\tan(z)+\cot(z)=-i\\\implies\dfrac{\tan^2(z)+1}{\tan(z)}=-i\\\implies\sec^2(z)=-i\tan(z)\\\implies\dfrac1{\cos^2(z)}=-\dfrac{i\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}\\\implies i=\sin(z)\cos(z)\\\implies i=\dfrac12\sin(2z)\\\implies\dfrac12\arcsin(2i)=z$$or$$z\approx0+0.72181773758941i$$

---

### My question

---

Is my solution to this seemingly difficult math equation correct, or what would I do to get the correct answer?

Comment: You were correct until the second to the last line and when you tried to find a numerical approximation. Since $\sin 2z$ is periodic, $\arcsin z$ returns a multivalued set so there is more than one answer. There is a simple fix, though. How would you fix it to include all of the possible answers?

Comment: @NinadMunshi So it should be $\dfrac12\arcsin(2i)+2i\pi k=z$ or what would it be?

Comment: What is the period of $\sin 2z$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi oh right, it'd be $i\pi k$.

Comment: That's still wrong. Even though complex numbers are involved it wouldn't do to forget fundamentals.

Comment: Maple provided a solution $z = -0.7853981634 - i\,0.2746530722$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the identity: $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{i z} & =\frac{1}{\cos z}+\frac{i}{\sin z} \\
& =\frac{2}{e^{i z}+e^{-i z}}-\frac{2}{e^{i z}-e^{-i z}} \\
& =\frac{-4 e^{-i z}}{e^{2 i z}-e^{-2 i z}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Rearranging and simplifying gives \begin{aligned}
e^{3 i z} & =-3 e^{-i z} \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad e^{4 i z} & =-3 \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad 4 i z & =\ln (-3) \\
\Leftrightarrow  \quad  \quad z & =\ln 3+\ln (-1) \\
& =-\frac{i}{4}(\ln 3+i \pi+2 n \pi)\\
& =\frac{1}{4}[(2 n+1) \pi-i \ln 3]
\end{aligned}
where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

*checked by [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20e%5E%7Bi%20z%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Ccos%20z%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bi%7D%7B%5Csin%20z%7D).

Answer (score 1):

Up until the end your work was correct. But we should be careful when we invert the $\sin z$. Using Euler's formula we have

$$2i = \frac{e^{i2z}-e^{-i2z}}{2i} \implies e^{i4z}+4e^{i2z}-1 = 0$$

which by quadratic formula means

$$e^{i2z} = -2\pm \sqrt{5}$$

This actually gives us two families of solutions, each with a periodicity. The LHS is $\pi$-periodic, not $i\pi$-periodic, so the final answer would be

$$z = \pi k - i \log\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}, \hspace{4pt}\frac{\pi}{2}+ \pi k -i\log\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+2}$$

for $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.